# How to link ImageMapster and sql data via Asp.Net?

Tags: jquery, sql, asp.net, imagemapster

I have a linkable map using ImageMapster. Now, data is static. But, I need them to be dynamic. Actually, I want to save image urls and other related items into sql database and retrive them and show them in a map in asp.net(vb).

Comment: are you creating mapping application in ASP?

Comment: I used this link: http://www.outsharked.com/imagemapster/
I prepared a map using js files and other objects in that site. I made a static map. But, I need to join it's data to sql server to be dynamic.

Comment: correct me if im wrong, do you mean you want to create an element that has to do with map based on your data in SQL?

Comment: Yes, exactly that

Comment: well for me you have to be specific with your question be more detailed, for example what problem are you facing now? Saving,Retreiving,I dont know. If I where you post a question that is relevant and by the way I will try give you a guide as an answer BRB.

Comment: I really don't know how to retrieve data sql in jquery.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/131116/discussion-between-nahid-and-shadow-fiend).

Comment: Ive seen your message. All I can say please edit your question and make it more specific

Comment: write a SQL database. Write some queries. Run the queries using .NET and retrieve the data in a structured format. Send the data to the client, possibly as JSON, or using some UI elements. Make sure it's in the right format you need, especially if it must integrate with a plugin like you described. These are the basic building blocks of any web based application. This is too broad for SO I'm afraid, you're asking us to write your whole application for you.